# write a java spring web service client for service now

Tags: java, web-services, spring, servicenow

My setup is as follows.I have a spring bean org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean using this interface:

```
<bean id="snIncidentService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="https://subdom.service-now.com/incident.do?WSDL" />
    <property name="namespaceUri" value="http://www.service-now.com" />
    <property name="serviceName" value="ServiceNow_incident" />
    <property name="portName" value="ServiceNowSoap" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="edu.liberty.webservice.SNIncident" />
    <property name="username" value="****" />
    <property name="password" value="****" />
</bean>


package edu.liberty.webservice;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

@WebService(name = "ServiceNowSoap", targetNamespace = "http://www.service-now.com/incident")
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface SNIncident {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "insert", action = "http://www.service-now.com/incident/insert")
    @WebResult(name = "insertResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.service-now.com/incident")  
    public InsertResponse insert(@WebParam(name="insert", targetNamespace = "http://www.service-now.com/incident") Insert inc);
}
```

Insert.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"skills",
"uponApproval",
```

... (about 50 more args)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "insert", namespace="http://www.service-now.com/incident")
public class Insert {

protected String skills;
@XmlElement(name = "upon_approval")
protected String uponApproval;
```

.. (same args)

I can call the webservice and service now creates the incident, but it is not taking into account the arguments I pass to it.

```
    Insert inc = new Insert();

    inc.setPriority(new BigInteger("1"));
    inc.setShortDescription("test WS");

    incidentService.insert(inc);
```

The SOAP message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
    <S:Body> 
      <ns2:insert xmlns:ns2="http://www.service-now.com/incident"> 
        <ns2:insert> 
          <priority>1</priority> 
          <short_description>test WS</short_description> 
        </ns2:insert>
      </ns2:insert>
     </S:Body>
   </S:Envelope>
```

I believe the problem is the second insert tag, but I cannont figure out how to stop it from being sent.

The WSDL can be seen at the service now demo site here:

https://demo05.service-now.com/incident.do?WSDL

user: admin

pw: admin

When I use wsimport the service method it creates includes all 67 arguments in the service method call. Unfortunately that works.  I really want to abstract all those arguments into an object.  Is there a way to get java to unroll the Insert object without having it add the extra insert tag to the SAOP message?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you're naming your Insert object as a parameter, which is where the second "

There may (must?) be a better option, but here's one that I found that seems to work:

Changing your insert method to take the parameters (named and with no namespace) instead of the Insert object should fix it.

```
public InsertResponse insert(
           @WebParam(name="priority", targetNamespace = "") BigInteger priority,
           @WebParam(name="short_description", targetNamespace = "") String shortDescription,
           @WebParam(name="assigned_to", targetNamespace = "") String assignedTo
);
```

Add parameters as needed for whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: That is similar to the wsimport approach.  I did not know I could chose the specicific args to include.  Now I have this error:

    Could not access remote service at [null]; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://www.service-now.com/incident}insertResponse but found: {null}insertResponse